# mysql query takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, internal-server-error

This query takes too long to produce result. And in php page it create 500 Internal server error.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tower_mac_address AS MAC_Address, tower_survey_no AS Survey_No 
FROM tower 
WHERE 
SUBSTR(REPLACE(tower_mac_address,':',''),7,6) 
NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM device_data 
    WHERE SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10)=CURRENT_DATE)
```

Please Help

Comment: Neither `WHERE SUBSTR(REPLACE(column...))` nor `WHERE SUBSTRING(column...)` can be indexed in MySQL, so you end up with a full table scan. Add additional columns storing precomputed results of these expressions, index them and use them in these conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is really bad. Since you are using SUBSTR(REPLACE ..... it cannot use index on tower_mac_address column. Similar situation for that inner query, you have SUBSTR... again. Instead of doing that, you can have prepared new column which has that SUBSTR(REPLACE... already, and add index on that column.

Btw, when you calculate values that you should use for that inner WHERE, instead of doing SUBSTRING to get date part of datetime, use [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely get rid of `substring` in subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM device_data 
WHERE SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10)=CURRENT_DATE;

--is the same as 
SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM device_data
WHERE `date_time` >=CURRENT_DATE AND `date_time`<CURRENT_DATE+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

But second query can use index on `date_time` column.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM device_data 
 WHERE date_time BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Comment: used this too. though too slow

Comment: Do you have an index on `date_time`. Or it's even better if you have composite index on (`date_time,deviceid`) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT tower_mac_address AS  MAC_Address, tower_survey_no AS Survey_No 
FROM tower LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT deviceid FROM device_data WHERE SUBSTR(date_time,1,10)=CURRENT_DATE) d ON SUBSTR(REPLACE(tower_mac_address,':',''),7,6) = d.deviceid
WHERE d.deviceid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: i need the mac address of devices which is not in the subquery. that is which is inactive on current date. This lists all the mac address

Comment: ok sorry my bad, then you need to change the last condition to `WHERE d.deveiceid IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the NOT IN.  MySQL does a very poor job of optimizing this.  At least the documentation sort of explains this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tower_mac_address AS MAC_Address, tower_survey_no AS Survey_No 
FROM tower t
WHERE  not exists
       (select 1
        from device_data dd
        where dd.deviceid = SUBSTR(REPLACE(t.tower_mac_address,':',''),7,6) and
              SUBSTRING(date_time,1,10)=CURRENT_DATE
       )
```

Here are additional recommendations:

1. Build an index on device_data.deviceid to speed up the subquery.
2. Store date_time as a datetime data type, not as a string.  This way, the comparison to CURRENT_DATE does not include an implicit conversion.
3. If "tow_mac_address" contains encoded information, consider splitting that out into separate fields.